# Right way to do a task after a particular interval of time

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, task-parallel-library, asp.net-4.0

I made a small winform app in which after every 10minutes ,app takes screenshot of the desktop and sends it using webservice in a base64 decoded format.

I used a timer control which fires in every 10mins and used background worker to update the last sent screenshot time on the UI.

The issue is that app is getting hang after some time , i did some googling and found that Task Parallel library is the right way for long runnning processes. But I don't know much about TPL.

Can you please guide that how can i implement TPL in my app
Please tell the right and the effcient way.

Code is

```
void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Interval = 600000 ; //10mins
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { screenShotFunction(); }));
    }
    else
    {
        screenShotFunction();
    }
}

private void screenShotFunction()
{

    printscreen = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(printscreen as Image);
    graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, printscreen.Size);

    mainSendFunction();

}

private void mainSendFunction()
{

    try
    {
        //code for webservice and base64 decoding
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Is this a virus/malware you're writing? Or a "productivity monitoring" app? ;-)

Comment: "productivity monitoring" , by all means ... now ... BACK TO WORK !!!

Comment: Are you sure there is no exceptions, like an OutOfMemory, or a system resource limit reached?

Comment: @Dommer what do you mean by malware/virus ? obviously doing some right stuff , if u have better idea then tell ?

Comment: @Pragmateek yes there are no exceptions

Comment: @hridya Just a joke. Hence the ;-) This sort of app could feasibly be used to capture people's screens for nefarious purposes.

Comment: If you have a bug in your code, then “I know, I'll use a completely different library” is probably not the right response.

Comment: @Dommer haha right ,but needed this app to monitor my co-workers work ;) ,They can start and stop the monitoring on button click..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in TPL but this should do:

First create a method to handle your task.

```
private async void ScreenShotTask()
{
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            _cancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            screenShotFunction();
            await Task.Delay(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10, 0), _cancelToken);
        }
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
        // what should happen when the task is canceled
    }
}
```

I've used `await Task.Delay` instead of `Thread.Sleep` because it can be canceled.

This is how you actually start the task:

```
private CancellationTokenSource _cancelSource;
private CancellationToken _cancelToken; // ScreenShotTask must have access to this
private void mainMethod()
{
    _cancelSource= new CancellationTokenSource();
    _cancelToken = cancelSource.Token;
    Task.Factory.StartNew(ScreenShotTask, _cancelToken, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
}
```

This is how you cancel the task:

```
_cancelSource.Cancel();
```

Comment: Why are you using `async void`? They are almost always a bad idea (unless you have to use it).